# Java 'project manager'? (comments, class view, etc...)

Tags: java, eclipse, documentation, comments, project-management

Reading the files of a few open source java projects I'm starting to think, that I'm not using all the advantages current developer tools have to offer.

The commentary often includes:

```
@param

@return

{@link *classname*}
```

etc.

is this 'only' good style / best practice or do it means the developer used some kind of tool to make his code easier to read for others? If so, could you get me started with some recommendations?

I'm currently using a pretty light version of eclipse and thought this would be sufficient, but if it is the common way to use such tools and the majority of programers use it, there are probably good reasons for it.

Comment: Have a read of https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/javadoc.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 2):

Thats called [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html). It's a syntax that creates a documentation for your Java classes. Since you are still using Eclipse, do this:

1. Click "Window" -> "Views" -> "Others" -> type "javadoc".
2. Open JavaDoc view. This view shows you how the docs will be rendered after all.

Now open any of your classes and type "/**" at the top of the classes definition and hit enter. You will see something like this:

```
/**
 *
 */
public class MyClass ...
```

It behaves like a multiline comment but always starts with a double asterisk. Having the carret within this block, hold crtl and hit space. It will show you all allowed tags you can use to markup the docs. Write a "@" sign and do the same to see all predefined javadoc tags. Add some of these, and see how the JavaDoc view is changing.

When you are done, click "Project" -> "Generate JavaDoc" -> "Finish". There will be a folder in your project called "docs" where you can find the documentation. Open the index.html in your browser.